# Google Sheets Script: Get First Row Number in Named Range

Tags: google-apps-script

In a script I'm setting a range using a Named Range. I need to get the first row number, to use for setting vals in other cols.

The Named Range 'ASX_100' is Top5!A**8**:A107...  so the first Row Number I need is 8, but as a script novice I can't find something online to help.  My code so far:

```
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sTop5 = ss.getSheetByName('Top5');
  const rASX100 = ss.getRange('ASX_100'), iLen = rASX100.getNumRows();
  // Get first sheet row number in range rASX100:
```

How should I go about this pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the range (`rASX100`), you can get its first row with the methods [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow) or [getRowIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrowindex):

```
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sTop5 = ss.getSheetByName('Top5');
const rASX100 = ss.getRange('ASX_100'), iLen = rASX100.getNumRows();
// Get first sheet row number in range rASX100:
const firstRangeRow = rASX100.getRow();
```

For the last row, you can use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow).

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: No problem! If this answered your question, please consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: No prob, I upvoted instead of accepting it as the answer - du-oh!  :)

Fixed now.